# Async unbuffered channel that blocks on read and on write

Tags: rust, async-await, channel, rust-futures

For threaded applications, the Rust standard library provides `std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel`, a buffered channel which blocks on the reading end when the buffer is empty and blocks on the writing end when the buffer is full. In particular, if you set the buffer size to 0, then any read or write will block until there is a matching write or read.

For async code, there is `futures::channel::mpsc::channel`, but this does not have the same behavior. Here the minimum capacity is the number of senders on the channel, which is greater than 0. The sending end can still block (because it implements `Sink`, so we can use `SinkExt::send` and `await` it), but only after there's at least one thing already in the buffer.

I took a look to see if there were any packages that provide the functionality I'm looking for, but I could not find anything. `Tokio` provides lots of nice async synchronization primitives, but none of them did quite what I'm looking for. Plus, my program is going to run in the browser, so I don't think I'm able to use a runtime like `Tokio`. Does anyone know of a package that fits my use case? I would try to implement this myself, since this almost feels like the most minimal use case for the `Sink` and `Stream` traits, but even a minimal implementation of these traits seems like it would be really complicated. Thoughts?

Edit: here's a minimal example of what I mean:

```rust
fn main() {
  let (tx, rx) = blocking_channel();

  let ft = async move {
    tx.send(3).await;
    println!("message sent and received");
  }

  let fr = async move {
    let msg = rx.recv().await;
    println!("received {}", msg);
  }

  block_on(async { join!(ft, fr) });
}
```

In this example, whichever future runs first will yield to the other, and only print after both `rx.recv` and `tx.send` have been called. Obviously, the receiving end can only progress after `tx.send` has been called, but I want the less obvious behavior of the transmitting end also having to wait.

Comment: Could you clarify what functionality you are looking for? Some examples of the behavior you want would be very helpful. Plus, you mention that there's no Tokio runtime in the browser, if you mean that you are compiling to WebAssembly, there's also no Rust standard library in the browser! AFAIK, you only have Javascript promises in terms of concurrency.

Comment: I think that futures work in the browser. There's crates that help you convert promises to futures, even implicitly. After all, async doesn't need access to the system unlike `std`, and you still have `alloc` and `core` in the browser.

Comment: I think tokio is currently working on WASM, although I'm not sure what their progress or their actual goals are. You could ask at the tokio discord.

Comment: Although I have to agree, none of their asyncs directly fit your usecase from what I understand.

Comment: I thought about writing one for you, but without `std` (using only `alloc` and `core`), it will be quite difficult. I think the more general response is that Rust's `async` is not quite there yet for `no-std` targets.

Comment: @A.Kriegman Futures can work in the browser by wrapping Promises from Javascript land, there's a crate form wasm-bindgen. You can find some experiments with channels in WASM Rust by using Javascript `SharedBuffer`. I mentioned the lack of `std` in the browser (well, in WASM) to point out that the support for sync primitives are much lower and experimental than you expect.

Comment: @Finomnis, I'm trying to write one but it's not going so well. I'd think that  `alloc` and `futures` would have everything we'd need, but I'm not sure. I think the appropriate container for the shared state would be an `Arc<Mutex<_>>`, but `Mutex` is in `std`... maybe we could start with a single threaded version using `Rc<_>`?

Comment: @A.Kriegman Managed to write one with `Rc`. It's rather quick and dirty, not the prettiest, and definitely needs a lot of testing, but maybe that can serve as a starting point?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I don't think something like that already exists.

Here is a quick proof-of-concept prototype I wrote for that. It's not the prettiest, but it seems to work. There might be a better struct layout than just wrapping everything in a `RefCell<Option<...>>`, though. And I don't particularly like the `sender_dropped` and `receiver_dropped` variables.

***Be sure to unittest it properly if used in production!!!***

```rust
extern crate alloc;

use alloc::rc::Rc;
use core::cell::RefCell;
use core::pin::Pin;
use core::task::{Poll, Waker};

use futures::SinkExt;
use futures::StreamExt;

struct Pipe<T> {
    send_waker: RefCell<Option<Waker>>,
    receive_waker: RefCell<Option<Waker>>,
    value: RefCell<Option<T>>,
    sender_dropped: RefCell<bool>,
    receiver_dropped: RefCell<bool>,
}

impl<T> Pipe<T> {
    fn new() -> Rc<Pipe<T>> {
        Rc::new(Self {
            value: RefCell::new(None),
            send_waker: RefCell::new(None),
            receive_waker: RefCell::new(None),
            sender_dropped: RefCell::new(false),
            receiver_dropped: RefCell::new(false),
        })
    }
}
impl<T> Pipe<T> {
    fn wake_sender(&self) {
        if let Some(waker) = self.send_waker.replace(None) {
            waker.wake();
        }
    }
    fn wake_receiver(&self) {
        if let Some(waker) = self.receive_waker.replace(None) {
            waker.wake();
        }
    }
}

pub struct PipeSender<T> {
    pipe: Rc<Pipe<T>>,
}

pub struct PipeReceiver<T> {
    pipe: Rc<Pipe<T>>,
}

pub fn create_pipe<T>() -> (PipeSender<T>, PipeReceiver<T>) {
    let pipe = Pipe::new();

    (PipeSender { pipe: pipe.clone() }, PipeReceiver { pipe })
}

impl<T> futures::Sink<T> for PipeSender<T> {
    type Error = ();

    fn poll_ready(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        let result = if *self.pipe.receiver_dropped.borrow() {
            Poll::Ready(Err(()))
        } else if self.pipe.receive_waker.borrow().is_some() && self.pipe.value.borrow().is_none() {
            Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
        } else {
            self.pipe.send_waker.replace(Some(cx.waker().clone()));
            Poll::Pending
        };

        // Wake potential receiver
        self.pipe.wake_receiver();

        result
    }

    fn start_send(self: Pin<&mut Self>, item: T) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let prev = self.pipe.value.replace(Some(item));
        assert!(prev.is_none(), "A value got lost in the pipe.");
        Ok(())
    }

    fn poll_flush(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        _: &mut futures::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        // Noop, start_send already completes the send
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn poll_close(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        _: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        // Noop, start_send already completes the send
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }
}

impl<T> futures::Stream for PipeReceiver<T> {
    type Item = T;

    fn poll_next(
        self: Pin<&mut Self>,
        cx: &mut std::task::Context<'_>,
    ) -> std::task::Poll<Option<Self::Item>> {
        let result = {
            let value = self.pipe.value.replace(None);
            if let Some(value) = value {
                Poll::Ready(Some(value))
            } else if *self.pipe.sender_dropped.borrow() {
                Poll::Ready(None)
            } else {
                self.pipe.receive_waker.replace(Some(cx.waker().clone()));
                Poll::Pending
            }
        };

        // Wake potential sender
        self.pipe.wake_sender();

        result
    }
}

impl<T> Drop for PipeSender<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.pipe.sender_dropped.replace(true);
        self.pipe.wake_receiver();
    }
}
impl<T> Drop for PipeReceiver<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.pipe.receiver_dropped.replace(true);
        self.pipe.wake_sender();
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    use std::time::Duration;

    let (mut sender, mut receiver) = create_pipe();

    tokio::join!(
        async move {
            for i in 0..5u32 {
                println!("Sending {i} ...");
                if let Err(_) = sender.send(i).await {
                    println!("Stream closed.");
                    break;
                }
                println!("Sent {i}.");
            }
            println!("Sender closed.");
        },
        async move {
            println!("Attempting to receive ...");
            while let Some(val) = receiver.next().await {
                println!("Received: {val}");

                println!("\n=== Waiting ... ===\n");
                tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;

                println!("Attempting to receive ...");
            }
            println!("Receiver closed.");
        }
    );
}
```

```
Sending 0 ...
Attempting to receive ...
Sent 0.
Sending 1 ...
Received: 0

=== Waiting ... ===

Attempting to receive ...
Sent 1.
Sending 2 ...
Received: 1

=== Waiting ... ===

Attempting to receive ...
Sent 2.
Sending 3 ...
Received: 2

=== Waiting ... ===

Attempting to receive ...
Sent 3.
Sending 4 ...
Received: 3

=== Waiting ... ===

Attempting to receive ...
Sent 4.
Sender closed.
Received: 4

=== Waiting ... ===

Attempting to receive ...
Receiver closed.
```